# Use one input as value for two buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to have two buttons that submit the same value (determined by the input field).

```
<form action="index.html">
    <button type="submit" name="btn1">Btn1</button>
    <button type="submit" name="btn2">Btn2</button>
    <input type="text" value="50">
</form>
```

It should result in:

```
Btn1 => index.html?Btn1=50
Btn2 => index.html?Btn2=50
```

Comment: Kind of a weird question.. Don't really understand why you would ever want to do this... What's the point of submitting multiple buttons while the input type is also in the form WITH the correct value? You can just get that value from text field?? What exactly are you trying to do? What's the desired result? Because in your question both buttons have the same value... makes no sense what so ever.. Why is this question even being upvoted?

Comment: the input defines a delay. the buttons trigger different actions using that value. just because you dont see any point in it, it doesnt mean there is none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two buttons can not send the same value as only one is clicked at a time. For one button to send the value you can try this :-

```
    <form action="index.jsp" method="get">
                <input type="text" value="50" name="input" id="input">
                <button type="submit" name="btn1" id="btn1" onclick="putValue()">Btn1</button>
                <button type="submit" name="btn2" id="btn2" onclick="putValue()">Btn2</button>
    </form>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function putValue(){
                    document.getElementById('btn1').value=document.getElementById('input').value;
                    document.getElementById('btn2').value=document.getElementById('input').value;
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: OP didn't added JavaScript tag then why you are adding JavaScript code?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7: Its his mistake. It is not possible without using javascript. Always think twice before down voting someone's answer.

Comment: was hoping for a pure html solution. thats why i didnt add javascript. thx

Answer (score 1):

call index.html according to teh button clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function setButton1Value(){
//call index.html?Btn1=50                    
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
                function setButton2Value(){
//call index.html?Btn2=50                    
}
</script>

 <form action="index.jsp" method="get">
                <input type="text" value="50" name="input" id="input">
                <button type="submit" name="btn1" id="btn1" onclick="setButton1Value()">Btn1</button>
                <button type="submit" name="btn2" id="btn2" onclick="setButton2Value()">Btn2</button>
 </form>
```